# How to update the flux store in react js after remove items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm having the 100's of record in data object. I have an option to delete items one by one. If i remove one item and tab to next screen and come back previous screen the data is not getting updated. That item still there which i removed previously. I have an endpoint to remove items from data table. My question is after removing item from list, how to update the store?

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

var MasterAPI = require('./Components/Flux/utils/MasterAPI');
var MasterStore = require('./Components/Flux/stores/MasterStore');

// Method to retrieve state from Stores
function getMasterState() {
  return {
    data: MasterStore.getMasterRefData()
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data:[]
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        MasterStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange.bind(this));
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        MasterStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange.bind(this));
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
          {this.state.map(function(el, i){
                return <div key={i}>
                    <div>{el.name}</div>
                    <button>Delete</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>;
    }
    _onChange() {
        this.setState(getMasterState());
    }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Why are you looping through the state. Shouldn't you loop through this.state.data?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that write one more method in the store to update the existing data, like this:

```
_updateData(index){
    this.data.splice(index,1);
    //emit data change so that component gets the update of this.data
}
```

Then in component pass the index of each grid in `_handleDeleteCLick()` method, use this index to remove the item and update the store, like this:

```
_handleDeleteCLick(index){
    MasterStore._updateData(index);
}
```

There is one change in your code, use `this.state.data` to create ui element instead of `this.state`, `this.state` is an `object` not an `array`. Try this:

```
return (
     <div>
          {this.state.map(function(el, i){
                return( 
                   <div key={i}>
                      <div>{el.name}</div>
                      <button onCLick={this._handleDeleteCLick(i)}>Delete</button>
                   </div>
                );
          }
     </div>;
)
```